# Ionic 2 - List does not update

Tags: list, ionic2, auto-update

I have an ion-list with a ngFor loop. Here is the html:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let kiosk of kiosks" (click)="goToKioskProfilePage(kiosk)">
        {{kiosk.name}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And here is the constructor:

```
kiosks: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams, public locationTracker: LocationTracker, public api: ApiService, public zone: NgZone) {

    this.kiosks = [];

    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.locationTracker.getGeolocation().then(location => {
            this.api.getClosestKiosks(location, constants.AMOUNT_OF_CLOSEST_KIOSKS).then(
                data => {
                    console.log("ready");
                    this.kiosks = data['data'];
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            );
        });
    });

}
```

The console logs "ready" but the list does not update. I already tried it with NgZone but it's still not working. Only when I open the sidemenu the list updates, but not before. Someone know how to fix that?

Comment: Does it work if you just run the assignment inside the zone (and not the entire geolocation call)? something like `this.zone.run(() => { this.kiosks = data['data']; }); `

Comment: You should not have to use zone. It shoud update without using zone, so the problem must be in other part of the code. Maybe kiosks must be public?

Comment: @CarlosAdrián since some async methods are being call (and thus, being run outside angular2) you must let angular know somehow that something has changed and the view must be updated. If `kiosk` property weren't public, an error should be shown in the console when trying to render the view.

Comment: I mean that it is not needed in THIS context, where we load the data from within our Ionic2 app. That code should refresh the list in an Ionic app without a zone call. That is why I say the problem comes from another part of the code.

Comment: Indeed, since the data comes from inside the app after the geolocation async call (and there isn't any http request, timeout event or user interaction) angular won't notice that something has changed in the data. But yeah, using zones should be the last option, it's not the best way to solve issues...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered a similar issue before. What fixed it for me was putting only the variable update/assignment in between zone.run(), as it's after the promise resolves that you want to update the values.

Try:

```
this.locationTracker.getGeolocation().then(location => {
    this.api.getClosestKiosks(location, constants.AMOUNT_OF_CLOSEST_KIOSKS).then(
        data => {
            console.log("ready");
            this.zone.run(() => {
                this.kiosks = data['data'];
            });
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
});
```